# Emacs will not visit new file but insists on opening a similar one

Tags: emacs, ido

The problem is quite simple but frustrating. When I try to visit a new file with `C-x C-f` which is named `basis.m` emacs keeps visiting the similar named file `haarbasis.m` which already exists in the same directory. It keeps prompting me for similar names and I am unable to visit a new empty file.  I had recently installed `elpy` for a python IDE if it makes any difference.

How can I force emacs not to visit a file with `C-x C-f` unless I explicitly state which file to visit?

Comment: I think you mean C-x C-f? C-x f runs set-fill-column. Does it work if you start Emacs with --no-init-file? If so, maybe you added some configuration to mess up C-x C-f? Possible workaround: Save your file with C-x C-w, then you get prompted for a filename.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`elpy` loads `idomenu` which in turn loads `ido`. What you are describing sounds like `ido`-powered completion of file names. You can disable it after `C-x C-f` by pressing `C-f`.

Comment: You can also press C-z to stop its annoying timeout.

Comment: Or use `C-j` instead of Return to force opening the filename as given without completing it.

Comment: Thank you all. I found all answers very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

As Alex mentions the string of packages that brought you to `ido-mode`, this answer depends on  the answer to your statement below, which may be why something is happening to you when you do `C-x C-f`

> When I try to visit a new file...

When your pointer/cursor is at the end of a word, `ido`will look for a file in the current directory with that name. It may even traverse down the relative path too if it's set up like a file directory structure e.g. `show/basis.m`

The commentor Jon O says, Even if this is happening `C-j` will create a new file for you.